# How to append each array of images to nsurlstring in objective c

Tags: objective-c

```
for(int i = 0; i <= self.images.count; i++){
    NSString *everyObject = [self.images objectAtIndex:i];
    self.everyString = self.avatarImageURLString;
    self.everyString = [self.everyString stringByAppendingString:everyObject];
    NSLog(@"cancate string:%@", self.everyString);
}
```

The error encountered:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 
>   -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is caused by an error in your loop's **condition**:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= self.images.count; i++){ ...
```

This basically iterates from zero to `images.count`, which is 2 here as you can see from the exception's message.

Indexing of NSArray's **starts from zero**, so valid indices include 0 and 1 in your case. Indexing with 2 will generate this exception since you are trying to reach an element which doesn't exist.

You can **fix** this e.g. by removing the equality from your condition:

```
for(int i = 0; i < self.images.count; i++){ ...
```